# How to solve "Modal dialog present: If you leave this page, any changes will be lost" in internet explorer and selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Following is my code. Below code is **able to remove the alert box but in console it throws error**

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present: If you leave this page, any changes will be lost.
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'"I am using intenet explorer 11

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id=ctl02_cp1_ucGI")).click();

Thread.sleep(4000);
if (ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent() != null)
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("window.onbeforeunload = function() {};"); 
    System.out.println("alert is present");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("alert is not present");
}

Thread.sleep(4000);
WebElement product1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='ctl00_cp1_ucGI_ddlProduct']"));
```

Comment: did my answer work for you or are you still getting the exception? Let me know if I can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to accept the alert via selenium

```
public void checkAlert() 
{
    try 
    {
        // Wait for the alert is present
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

        // Switch to the alert
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

        // Close the alert
        alert.accept();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        //exception handling
    }
}
```